How to add support for SEOPress canonical URL in ShowcaseIDX plugin?
I am trying to add support for canonical URL in ShowcaseIDX plugin for SEOPress but not able to add. I tried updating the code of /plugins/showcase-idx/3/seo.php where the filter add_filter('wpseo_canonical', $canonical); is defined but for some reason it is not working.
I also tried to update the value of the $canonicalUrl variable in /plugins/showcase-idx/2/showcaseidx.php but it is also not working.
Can anyhelp me overwriting the canonical URL value in the ShowcaseIDX plugin? I tried to reach the ShocaseIDX support but they are saying they have other priorities to work upon.
Thanks in advance!
I want to call the value of current page URL using this- home_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); regardless the SEO plugin.

try this in your function php
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'rel_canonical' );
add_action( 'wp_head', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\my_custom_rel_canonical' );

function my_custom_rel_canonical() {
global $wp;
$current_url = home_url( $wp->request );
if ( is_singular() ) {
    printf(
        '<link rel="canonical" href="%1$s"  />' . PHP_EOL,
        esc_url( $current_url )
    );
}
}

